# How to split AJAX response into two divs

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

How I could get AJAX response splitted in two separate divs?

Situation: I have custom post type (case-studies) filter by custom taxonomy(case study category). On page load I query by exact category. But when I filter it by category I want to get AJAX response divided into two parts. First one even posts appears in filtered-post-top div and odd posts appears in filtered-post-bottom div.

Here is what I have achieved so far.

functionts.php file:

```
function filter_ajax() {


  $category = $_POST['category'];
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'case-studies',
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'tax_query' => array(
      array(
          'taxonomy' => 'case_study_categories',
          'terms' => $category
      )
    )
  );
  
  $query = new WP_Query($args);

  if($query->have_posts()) :
      while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
        get_template_part( 'partials/case-studies-archive-post' );
      endwhile;
  endif;

    wp_reset_postdata(); 
      die();
  }
```

ajaxRequest.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.filter-item > span').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var category = $(this).data('category');
        console.log(category);
        data = {
            'action': 'filter',
            'category': category
        };

        $.ajax({
            url : wp_ajax.ajax_url,
            data : data,
            type : 'post',
            success: function(result) {
                $('.filtered-posts').html(result);
                console.log(result);
            },
            error: function(result) {
                console.warn(result);
            }
        });
    })

});
```

Archive-case-studies.php

```
<section>
        <div class="filtered-posts-top">
            <?php 
                $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'case-studies',
                    'posts_per_page' => 4,
                    'tax_query' => array(
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'case_study_categories',
                            'terms' => 14
                        )
                      )
                );
                $counter = 0;
                $query = new WP_Query($args);
                
                if ($query->have_posts()) :
                    while ( $query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
                    $counter++;
                            if( $counter % 2 == 0 ) : 
                                get_template_part( 'partials/case-studies-archive-post' );
                            endif;
                    endwhile;
                endif;
                wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="case-studies-categories">
            <?php
            $args = array(
                'taxonomy'  => 'case_study_categories'
            );
            $categories = get_terms( $args );
            ?>
                <?php foreach ( $categories as $cat ) :?>
                    <div class="filter-item">
                        <span  data-category="<?php echo $cat->term_id;?>"><?php echo $cat->name; ?></span>
                    </div>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="filtered-posts-bottom">
            <?php 
                $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'case-studies',
                    'posts_per_page' => 4,
                    'tax_query' => array(
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'case_study_categories',
                            'terms' => 14
                        )
                      )
                );
                $counter = 0;
                $query = new WP_Query($args);
                
                if ($query->have_posts()) :
                    while ( $query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
                    $counter++;
                        if( $counter % 2 == 1 ) : 
                                get_template_part( 'partials/case-studies-archive-post' );
                        endif;
                    endwhile;
                endif;
                wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
        </div>
      
    </section>
```

Maybe someone will have idea how to solve the issue.

Comment: This script dump is too fat / Needs More Focus.   Please craft a [mcve].

Comment: As noted, this is a lot for us to process so I can only give vague suggestions. CSS has things like grid, flex box, columns and n-th child selectors, can you rethink your render and solve this that way? I think you are sending HTML, can it be wrapped in a JSON that can be iterated over? Otherwise, you can try adding the HTML to a temporary fragment and iterating over that.